# pentaho error when y put an oracle sql query with any parameter of data range input component

Tags: parameters, datasource, pentaho

Good morning,
I have a sql that I enter in datasource and it shows me results. What I want is to put a date range input component and take the two parameters from there to pass them to the sql. In the sql, the parameters are set to $ {date_from} and $ {date_to}. Once I put it, the table is not shown, the query is erro. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Can you share an image of the whole step configuration. might be you're not using variable substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Here I show an image of how I have the layout panel configured.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Here I upload how I have configured the parameters

[image]

Here I show how I have configured the table where I will show the data

[image]

Here I teach how is the datasource and then I show the query

[image]